# Run a task every minute in spring jpa but HikariPool shuts down

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

i'm trying to run a task every minute in spring data jpa. I want to do it with annotations:

**JpademoApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class JpademoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (var context = SpringApplication.run(JpademoApplication.class, args)) {
            var app = context.getBean(RunEveryMinute.class);
            app.run();
        }
    }
}
```

And my class with the method which i want to run every minute:

```
@Component
public class RunEveryMinute {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RunEveryMinute.class);

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000)
    public void run() {
        log.info("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

It is working but the problem is, after that my HikariPool shutting down so it do it only one time instead every minute:

```
2020-01-31 09:34:47.479  INFO 27966 --- [           main] com.example.jpademo.JpademoApplication   : Starting JpademoApplication on edv-vm with PID 27966 (/home/.../Downloads/jpademo/target/classes started by ...in /home/.../Downloads/jpademo)
2020-01-31 09:34:47.483  INFO 27966 --- [           main] com.example.jpademo.JpademoApplication   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2020-01-31 09:34:48.127  INFO 27966 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-01-31 09:34:48.153  INFO 27966 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 16ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-01-31 09:34:48.679  INFO 27966 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-01-31 09:34:49.144  INFO 27966 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-01-31 09:34:49.280  INFO 27966 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-01-31 09:34:49.374  INFO 27966 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.4.10.Final}
2020-01-31 09:34:49.604  INFO 27966 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-01-31 09:34:49.742  INFO 27966 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2020-01-31 09:34:49.975  INFO 27966 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-01-31 09:34:49.984  INFO 27966 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-01-31 09:34:50.083  INFO 27966 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2020-01-31 09:34:50.107  INFO 27966 --- [   scheduling-1] com.example.jpademo.ScheduledTasks       : The time is now 09:34:50
2020-01-31 09:34:50.112  INFO 27966 --- [           main] com.example.jpademo.JpademoApplication   : Started JpademoApplication in 3.487 seconds (JVM running for 5.109)
2020-01-31 09:34:50.113  INFO 27966 --- [           main] com.example.jpademo.ScheduledTasks       : The time is now 09:34:50
2020-01-31 09:34:50.115  INFO 27966 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Shutting down ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2020-01-31 09:34:50.116  INFO 27966 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-01-31 09:34:50.116  INFO 27966 --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2020-01-31 09:34:50.120  INFO 27966 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-01-31 09:34:50.136  INFO 27966 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Can anybody helped out with that ?

Comment: if you follow [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/) guide everything should work. From your provided code, change the `@EnableScheduling` to your main class. If it not working provide more code

Comment: provided to the main class but same behavior. what do you mean with more code ?

Comment: it semms that any config in your app is not correct. I just created a simple app with a datasource and it works as espected

Comment: @Patrick can you explain or give ref to why it is important to have `@EnableScheduling` in Main Class only.

Comment: can you mention your maven/gradle file? and what db are you using H2 or HSQL?

Comment: @Patrick you said it workied as espected, its just not true ! It doenst work with a new spring jpa starter and a h2. i also provide all my code above.

Comment: H2, i will provide a full minimal example

Comment: @miiiii its not important. But I dont see the full code and wanted to see if configuration is mismatched.

Comment: @Patrick this is nr. 5 ! you have all the code above !!

Comment: @user182410 change your main method to the following: `public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(JpademoApplication.class, args);
    }`

Comment: and how should i run my class RunEveryMinute with that ?

Comment: @user182410 it will run automatically. Its known by the spring context

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206957/discussion-between-user182410-and-patrick).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main method is not working as expected. You should change the main method to the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class JpademoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JpademoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The spring context will automatically look up all `@Component` annotated classes and runs the methods which are annotated with `@Scheduled`. No need for any ohter configuration in your main class.

BTW: All `@Scheduled` methods run in an own thread. For Database actions you should annotate the methods with `@Transactional` for an own session.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that your app is closed immediately after invoking of main method. (So, answer by miiiii is correct). 
Do you have a web app?
If yes - then you can add

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

dependency. This dependnecy contains servlet container which prevents app to shutdown. 
Or use answer from miiiii

Also note, that you don't need to call `JpademoApplication.run` manually - spring does it automatically. 
So, if you add web starter - your main method should like

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JpademoApplication.class, args));
    }
```

If your application isn't web application - you need to prevent closing, you can use the following code for that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JpademoApplication.class, args));
        Thread.currentThread().join(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Application.properties

`spring.main.lazy-initialization=true`

is stopping the execution of `@Scheduled()` Methods.

Solution: `@Lazy(false)`

Example:

```
@Component
@Lazy(false)
public class RunEveryMinute {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RunEveryMinute.class);

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000)
    public void run() {
        log.info("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```